# Batch requests placed via nodejs request.get using rxjs

Tags: node.js, request, rxjs

I am currently using the following function to create a `Promise` from the result of calling `request.get`:

```
function dlPromiseForMeta(meta) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        meta.error = false;

        var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(meta.filePath);

        fileStream.on('error', function (error) {
            meta.error = true;
            console.log('filesystem ' + meta.localFileName + ' ERROR: ' + error);
            console.log('record: ' + JSON.stringify(meta));
            reject(meta);
        });

        fileStream.on('close', function () {
            resolve(meta);
        });

        request.get({
            uri: meta.url,
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            followAllRedirects: true,
            pool: {
                maxSockets: 1000
            },
            timeout: 10000,
            agent: false
        })
            .on('socket', function () {
                console.log('request ' + meta.localFileName + ' made');
            })
            .on('error', function (error) {
                meta.error = true;
                console.log('request ' + meta.localFileName + ' ERROR: ' + error);
                console.log('record: ' + JSON.stringify(meta));
                reject(meta);
            })
            .on('end', function () {
                console.log('request ' + meta.localFileName + ' finished');
                fileStream.close();
            })
            .pipe(fileStream);
    });
}
```

This works fine except when I am trying to call it too many times, as in the example below, where `imagesForKeywords` returns an `rxjs` `Observable`:

```
imagesForKeywords(keywords, numberOfResults)
    .mergeMap(function (meta) {
        meta.fileName = path.basename(url.parse(meta.url).pathname);
        meta.localFileName = timestamp + '_' + count++ + '_' + meta.keyword + '_' + meta.source + path.extname(meta.fileName);
        meta.filePath = path.join(imagesFolder, meta.localFileName);

        return rxjs.Observable.fromPromise(dlPromiseForMeta(meta))(meta);
    });
```

I start getting `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` errors when the source observable becomes sufficiently large.

So what I would like to do is somehow batch what happens in `mergeMap` for every, say, `100` entries... so I do those 100 in parallel, and each batch serially, and then merge them at the end.

How can I accomplish this using `rxjs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest thing to use is `bufferTime()` which triggers after a certain number of ms but also has a parameter at the end for count.

Using a timeout seems useful, in case there's a stream pattern that does not reach the batch limit in a reasonable time.

If that does not fit your use-case, comment me with some more details and I will adjust accordingly.

Your code will look like this,

- **bufferTime** as described above
- **forkjoin** - run the buffer contents in parallel and emit when all return
- **mergeMap** - coalesce the results

```js
imagesForKeywords(keywords, numberOfResults)
  .mergeMap(function (meta) {
    meta.fileName = path.basename(url.parse(meta.url).pathname);
    meta.localFileName = timestamp + '_' + count++ + '_' + meta.keyword + '_' + meta.source + path.extname(meta.fileName);
    meta.filePath = path.join(imagesFolder, meta.localFileName);
    return meta;
  })
  .bufferTime(maxTimeout, null, maxBatch)
  .mergeMap(items => rxjs.Observable.forkJoin(items.map(dlPromiseForMeta)))
  .mergeMap(arr => rxjs.Observable.from(arr))
```

---

Here's a runnable mockup to show it working. Have commented out the last `mergeMap` to show the buffering.

I have assumed a couple of things,

- imagesForKeywords breaks keywords into observable stream of keyword
- there is one keyword per dlPromiseForMeta call

```js
// Some mocking
const imagesForKeywords = (keywords, numberOfResults) => {
  return Rx.Observable.from(keywords.map(keyword => { return {keyword} }))
}
const dlPromiseForMeta = (meta) => {
  return Promise.resolve(meta.keyword + '_image')
}

// Compose meta - looks like it can run at scale, since is just string manipulations.
const composeMeta = meta => {
  // meta.fileName = path.basename(url.parse(meta.url).pathname);
  // meta.localFileName = timestamp + '_' + count++ + '_' + meta.keyword + '_' + meta.source + path.extname(meta.fileName);
  // meta.filePath = path.join(imagesFolder, meta.localFileName);
  return meta;
}

const maxBatch = 3
const maxTimeout = 50 //ms
const bufferedPromises = (keywords, numberOfResults) =>
  imagesForKeywords(keywords, numberOfResults)
    .map(composeMeta)
    .bufferTime(maxTimeout, null, maxBatch)
    .mergeMap(items => Rx.Observable.forkJoin(items.map(dlPromiseForMeta)))
    //.mergeMap(arr => Rx.Observable.from(arr))

const keywords = ['keyw1', 'keyw2', 'keyw3', 'keyw4', 'keyw5', 'keyw6', 'keyw7'];
const numberOfResults = 1;
bufferedPromises(keywords, numberOfResults)
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```